# Retrofit display request details - body, headers, etc

Tags: android, retrofit

I can't seem to find anything in Retrofit docs regarding how to display any Request details.

Specifically, I want to see JSON from POST Request Body.

The problem is that my request to the server fails with no details message, and I suspect that something is wrong on my side.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Maybe there is a better way to achieve this, but you can configure your log level using the RestAdapter.Builder like:

```
   RestAdapter.Builder builder=...
   builder.setLogLevel(LogLevel.FULL).setLog(new RestAdapter.Log() {
            public void log(String msg) {
               Log.i("retrofit", msg);
            }
        });
```

Comment: Going to accept that as there are no other answers and test it on my next project with Retrofit=) Thanks

Comment: This solution is no longer applicable. Retrofit APIs are all different now

Answer (score 2):

here is an updated answer for retrofit 2.0

```
 HttpLoggingInterceptor body = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
        body.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
        builder.addInterceptor(body);

        OkHttpClient client = builder.build();

        retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(baseUrl)
                .client(client)
```